# Googlemaps Routing, Blue Routing line does not show on map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, asynchronous, url-routing

I am new to Java Script and have a simple problem:
I do routing with Googlemaps API (TransitLayer). 
The routing works, the direction panel is succesfully created,
but unfortunately the blue routing line doesn't appear on the map.
It probably has to do with my asynchronous initialsing of the map. (Callback function)
See below my javascript function
and here the link to my page:
[My website](http://www.home.hs-karlsruhe.de/~loax1012/js_project.html) (Tab 2: routing).

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

```
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
routingcounter = 0;
var routingmap;
var mapOptions;

function initialize_routing() {
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
   mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(51.510799, -0.134332)
  };
    routingmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mycanvas'),
      mapOptions);
  directionsDisplay.setMap(routingmap);
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));

  var transitLayer = new google.maps.TransitLayer();
  transitLayer.setMap(routingmap);

}


function loadScript() {

  if(routingcounter == 0)
  {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize_routing";
  document.body.appendChild(script);
  routingcounter++;
  }

}


function compute_route()
{


    var start = $('from').value;
    var over = $('over').value;
    var waypts = [];

    var end = $('to').value;

    if ($('from').value == "" || $('to').value=="")
    {
        alert("Fill in From- and To-Textfields! Try again!");
        return;
    }

    start += ",London"

    end += ",London"

    if($('over').value == "")
    {
        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
        };
    }
    else
    {
        over += ",London"

        waypts.push({
          location:over,
          stopover:true
      });


        var request = {
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            waypoints: waypts,
            optimizeWaypoints: true,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.TRANSIT
        };
    }




  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) 
    {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
    else
    {
        alert("No matching places found. Retry please!");
        $('from').value == "";
        $('over').value == "";
        $('to').value == "";

    }
  });




}

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize_routing);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your answer may be with the options of the `DirectionsRenderer`. You can feed it options, and in most cases, you'll need this.

```
 {
   suppressPolylines: false,
   polylineOptions: // polylineOptions object here
 }
```

The `suppressPolylines` will enable polylines on your map. The options can then be set: fill, stroke, etc, using the second object, the same way you would configure a polyline.

Build a fiddle from your code and I'll edit it to implement it.

**Edit**: Corrected your code - fiddle http://tinker.io/14b5a .

Points to note:

1. it's `$("#elementID")`, not `$("elementID")`
2. it's `$("#input").val()`, not `$("#input").value`
3. Google Maps API does not take a callback (this is a very serious point as it prevents AMD loaders from loading it)
4. When all the points above are fixed, the line works all by itself.

Comment: @user1677716: Fixed it for you.

Comment: thanks very much! still i cannot fix my code, if i copy your code from tinker to my javascriptfile the page (tab) doesnot display at all. here is my entire project: http://www.file-upload.net/download-7640212/project_26-05.zip.html. I am a liitble bit confused right now. anyway, thanks so much so far...

Comment: @user1677716: Instead of blindly copying, actually **look** and **understand** the changes I've made. It's your assignment - you'll no doubt be asked questions on it.

Comment: you make it sound like i did not work for the assignment and would have just used your code. i just tried it out and it didnt work, thats all. you don't have to help me, i think i'd rather get input from people who are much less arrogant

Comment: @user1677716: "if I copy your code". I specifically took out all the references to your app for the tinker, as there was no other way to get it going. I also told you what I've changed, which would have allowed you to find and correct the errors in your code. It's not as if I went "Here, have this" - you've got a list of all the stuff I changed that needed to be changed.

Comment: I see your point and admittedly my way of communicating was not good. anyway, i thought your post was a birt disresepctful. anyway, i want to thank you for your effort, one can see that you know a lot about javascript.